# how can i know if the scroll is at the start?

Tags: reactjs, angularjs

i did this code when i was working with angularjs, right now i am working with reactjs, this is a demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/UP9Wvj6BMLhNXreVDIR9?p=preview&preview

app.directive('scroller', function($window){

```
return {

    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
        
        elem.on('scroll', function(evt){
           console.log(elem[0].scrollHeight);
           console.log(elem[0].scrollTop);
           console.log(elem[0].offsetHeight);
           
           if(elem[0].scrollHeight < elem[0].scrollTop + elem[0].offsetHeight){
             alert('llego');
           }
           
        });
    }

}
```

});

this code i used to know if the scroll was at the end, right now i need to know if the scroll is at the start but i need in reactjs, if is at the start the scroll dont should moving, always should be at the start

Comment: This code has nothing to do with AngularJs nor React.

Comment: You can use Intersection Observer API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#creating_an_intersection_observer